# How do I handle answers that should be comments?

Tags: discussion

Okey I am a bit new to this whole thing and at a loss. I have have made a question, someone has answered and then someone else who doesn't have enough points to comment on that answer makes a new answer which infact should be read as a comment to an answer to make sense. The question is here:

[No indentation at the beginning of environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/no-indentation-at-the-beginning-of-environment)

What can I do? Reading this question and the answers are breaking down with answers answering other answers while moving up and down in the list depending on their votes. It's already becomming a mess if you ask me. Is this perhaps just business as usual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the assumption that it is a good comment (as it was in this case - but then I have to say that as the user in question has Serious Powers on my local computer network), here's my recommendations:

1. Vote up the answer.  If enough people do this, that user will get over the threshold and the problem won't arise again.
2. Leave a comment on the answer that it *should* have been on saying, "Note X's comment on this.".
3. If it's a comment that really ought to be read at the same time as the other answer, then it ought to be folded in to that answer, so in the comment left on the other answer, say, "I think you should included X's answer in this."
4. If it's *really* a mess, answer the question yourself, folding in all the pertinent points from the other answers, and then accept that answer.  Make sure you explain what you're doing and make that answer CW.  (You might have to wait a little before accepting it, I don't remember if there's a time delay.)
5. As the Norwegians say, *slapp av*.  Namely, relax.  It doesn't happen that often that it's annoying and specific instances can always be sorted out on an individual basis.  Moderators can edit *anything* so if no-one else edits their answers or whatever, you can flag it for Moderator attention and ask them to clean it up a little.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the commenting threshold is at 50 rep, which shouldn't be hard to come by. If you're already on another SE site with at least 200 reputation, then you'd get bonus 100 points on each site you sign on afterwards, which is sufficient for commenting right away.

That being said, it *is* annoying that users with low reputation cannot comment on questions, but I guess that is by design (comments cannot be downvoted).